# Advice on best technique to compare data to a horizontal line with slope = 0?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear

I have run into some difficulties figuring out which statistical test is best to use in the following scenario:

Consider a typical line y = mx + b

For a given domain on a plane, say 0 to 1, I have a set of data points that make up a line with some small slope m, where 0 < m < 1. I would like to figure out the best statistical test to determine whether that line is statistically different from a straight horizontal line, i.e. a line whose slope m = 0, which is essentially  y=1.

Because the intercepts b are distinct, it would not suffice to simply compare the slopes m between both lines. But even at that, since one slope = 0, I can't seem to figure out how to compare the lines.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I am having trouble understanding how the intercept comes up in this. Could you please explain that in more detail.

Comment: For example, y = 0x+1 and y=0x+4 are both horizontal lines with identical slopes but lie at different areas of the plane. Im my case, y = 0x + 1 and the other line share similar slopes (though as stated for the second line 0<m<1) and intercepts that are close so between 0.8 and 1 let's say. Is that more clear?

Comment: No. It seems like you’re just interested in testing the slope, which is totally possible to do, regardless of the slope.

Comment: ok, what is the approach you'd suggest when one slope = 0?

Comment: That’s the standard hypothesis test of the slope coefficient that you would get in the regression output in standard statistical software like R. $H_0: \text{slope is zero}$ vs $H_a:\text{slope is not zero}$, and then the intercept does not come up at all. Is this all you’re looking to do?

Comment: Yes. You're describing the hypothesis though. What is the actual statistical test?

Comment: It’s called a t-test or an F-test of a regression coefficient.

Comment: When you have a straight line, variance = 0, can't use the F or t-test cause ypu're dividing by 0...hence my question